# Could Google Play filter base on OS

Tags: java, android, google-play

I have developed an application which is only intended for Jelly Bean ( not ICS ). Is it anyway for Google Play to prevent ICS device from download my application?

If the same device has the with a diff.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [Filters on Play Store](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) and you can try by adding to `AndroidManifest.xml` by these values.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

For Jelly Bean, the `minSdkVersion` should be 16, then Google Play will automatically filter it. You can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Answer (score 0):

The minSdkVersion attribute in your manifest. [Android sdk version](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidMainifest.xml file you should declare the minimun sdk to 16.

```
android:minSdkVersion="16"
```